# How to change touched portions of a UImage to clear colour?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to give a feature in my iPhone/iPad app to enable users to crop an image by swiping away the unwanted portions with fingers. So I want to know how I can change these touched portions alone of the Image to clear color.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I am able to draw lines on the image with other colors. I am able to to crop in rectangular shape. But not sure how to dynamically chip away parts as user swipes.